# How to fix argument type 'int?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num'

Tags: flutter

I am trying to do a computation. But my value is from a `int?` and it not letting me to do it. the error is `The argument type 'int?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num'.` I don't understand.

Here is my code:

```
  String goal= "1000";
  String workout = "0";
  String remaining = "";
  int? _total;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dbHelper = DbHelper();
    _calcTotal();
  }

  void _calcTotal() async{
    var total = (await dbHelper.calcTotal())[0]['total'];
    print(total);
    setState(() => _total = total);
  } 



int resulttext = int.parse(goal) - _total + int.parse(workout);
remaining = resulttext.toString();
```

Answer (score 9):

I solved my problem by this. I just add this line:

```
var total = _total?.toInt() ?? 0;
```

before this:

```
int resulttext = int.parse(goal) - (total + int.parse(workout));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the datatype to 'dynamic' instead of 'int'

Answer (score 1):

```html
 setState(() {
    sliderlength = _carouselImages!.length;
  });
```

This will fix your problem .

Answer (score 0):

```
 **int amt = 0; 
 amt = int.tryParse(widget.price)!;
setState(() {
      _increment();
      sum = sum + amt;
    });
in this code widget.price comes from previcious widgets and price is actually  stored in a Firebase as a string so then i convert into int first and assign a new variable i works for me**
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).