# Error: The argument type 'int?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'

Tags: flutter, authentication

I want to get data message and get error "The argument type 'int?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'".

```
Widget content() {
  return StreamBuilder<List<MessageModel>>(
    stream: MessageService()
      .getMessagesByUserId(userId: authProvider.user.id),
```

Comment: please, add more information. Where specifically is this argument expected? Where do you get the value you're giving from?

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/q/70144149/10157127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parameter type for the getMessagesByUserId function has a non nullable int type, but the authProvider user id field is a nullable field, for the instances when the user is authenticated.

```
// What you have
...
Widget content() {
  return StreamBuilder<List<MessageModel>>(
    stream: MessageService()
      .getMessagesByUserId(userId: authProvider.user.id),
  );
}
...

// What should be
Widget content() {
  return StreamBuilder<List<MessageModel>>(
    stream: MessageService()
      .getMessagesByUserId(userId: authProvider.user.id!),
  );
}

// Or other option
Widget content() {
    return authProvider.user.id ? StreamBuilder<List<MessageModel>>(
        stream: MessageService()
        .getMessagesByUserId(userId: authProvider.user.id),
    ) : Center(child: Text('User Not Logged In'));
}
```